# USB drive unresponsive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, freeze, windows-server

I have a 2TB harddrive connected via USB 3.0. This drive has been working fine for a while now.

Quite often, when opening an arbitrary folder on the drive, it just freezes for about half a minute.

I have opened up HD Tune to monitor the disk access. What I saw was that there is no drive activity going on at the moment of the freeze. Neither is there any activity before the freeze.

I have no idea on how to debug this issue, so therefore I'm here.

I had found another similar question on SU here, but that person was using linux. I have no linux at my disposal at the moment so I was hoping to find some Windows debugging tools?

At the moment I am running a HD Tune health test, which seems to go fine. I plan to run a Seatools test as well. These test came back positive, so no issues found.

I've copied the entire content of the harddrive to other drives and I'm going to try a lowlevel format now. Hope this resolved the issue. Otherwise I'm taking it back to the store for a new one.

Ps: this drive is connected on a Windows server 2012 system.

Thanks,

Edit:

I've decided to backup all my data and try a format. What I'v noticed here, is that while copying the transfer stalls from time to time. When I navigate the drive at that point, I can navigate the drive (because of the index I suppose). When I try to open a file it fails. And logically, when the transfer continues the file suddenly does open.

Am I looking at a broken enclosure here? I'd like to open it up, but I think it's the "open me once, close me never" kind of enclosure and I don't want to void the warranty.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on another system?

Comment: I will try this today!

Comment: @valsidalv I have plugged in the harddrive in my desktop computer and the issue is indeed the same. It makes the explorer window freeze. From what I can tell the problem is much more present even. Any suggestions?

Comment: For the time being a format of the drive (not quick) seems to have fixed the issue? I will report back if the problem still persists..

Comment: In response to your edit: if it's still under warranty definitely try contacting the company for support. If they can't help you and the problem keeps reoccurring then hopefully you can replace it with another one!

Comment: It seems the drive is failing, contact the vendor to get a replacement